# Looking for the right url in an Ajax json call

Tags: jquery, json, telerik

I have the next code in my cshtml for filling a partial view from the result of selecting a row in a telerik grid control.

```
    function onRowSelected(e) {
    var tracksGrid = $('#Tracks').data('tGrid');
    articleID = e.row.cells[0].innerHTML;

    alert(articleID)

    var recordID = { id : articleID };

    $.ajax(
     {
         type: 'html',
         contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
         data: JSON.stringify(recordID),
         dataType: 'json',
         url: '@Url.Action("Tracks", "Home")',
         success: function (result) {
             alert('Success');
         },

         error: function (error) {
             alert('Fail');
     }
 });
}
```

The alert shows an id. so far so good.

But I think the url is wrong and I don't what to do.
In the home controller the Tracks expects an string id.

```
 public ActionResult Tracks(String id)
```

Can you help me?

Thanks

@3nigma Nice! In the error.responseText I see the _tracks as html. e.g. fieldset, legend, table and the 10  with data. 
In my partialView: @model IEnumerable a Fieldset, Legend table  a @foreach (var item in Model) and tr has a item.Description. 
What else can I do??

this is my partialview

```
@model IEnumerable<Web.Models.Tracks>           
<fieldset>
    <legend>Tracks</legend>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="display-label">
                    unitno</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="display-label">
                    Trackno</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="display-label">
                    Description</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        { 
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="display-field">
                        item.Unitno
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="display-field">
                        item.Trackno
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="display-field">
                        item.Description
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>

        }
    </table>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $.ajax(
     {
         type: 'POST',  //or GET or PUT etc see the DOCS for more info
         contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
         data:{id:articleID },
         dataType: 'json',
         url: '@Url.Action("Tracks", "Home")',
         success: function (result) {
             alert('Success');
         },

         error: function (error) {
             alert('Fail');
     }
 });
```

[`jquery ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Not 100% perfect. I can step into the tracks action then the partial view will be filled with the result of the linq query. But the partialview will NOT be shown on the page.

Comment: @NotFairTreated i didnt understand you are facing problem in getting/loading the partial view?

Comment: I will try to explain. If I hit F11 in vs2010 I can step into all methods and cshtml files. By following these steps I can see the model in tracks will be filled with the right values. (        @foreach (var item in Model) stepping throu) But on return:             return PartialView("Tracks", tracks); It fails.  alert('fail') is shown. So the result is for some reason not good.

Comment: @NotFairTreated the problem seems to be with your view can you step into your view? in the `error` callback do `alert(error.responseText)` also check in the firebug what do get in the response ?